# Map container to hostname other than localhost in Docker for Mac

Tags: docker, networking

I am creating an Nginx container that I would like to access locally at `http://api`. Using Docker Machine, I assumed running `docker-machine create default` and `docker-machine ip default` to receive the IP and editing my hosts file to something like this:

`# docker-machine ip default --> 192.168.99.100`
`192.168.99.100  api`

should map requests to `api\` to the Docker Machine IP and serve my content.

Two things are confusing me:

1. I launch Docker through the Mac App and can create Nginx containers and access content at `http://localhost`. However, running `docker-machine ls` returns no machines. This is confusing because I thought Docker had to run on a VM.
2. Starting from scratch and starting Docker Machine, then spinning up containers seems to have no effect. In other words, I still can access content at `http://localhost` but not `http://api`

Instead of accessing my container at `http://localhost` I want to access it at `http://api`. How do I do this?

I'm using Docker for Mac 17.12 and Docker Machine 0.14.

Comment: You probably installed `Docker for mac` rather than `Docker toolbox`. In toolbox, things used to work using a virtual machine as you were expecting, while in Docker for mac there is no virtualbox VM anymore. Have a look here: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/docker-toolbox/#the-docker-for-mac-environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the base of your this question:

> Instead of accessing my container at http://localhost I want to access
>   it at http://api. How do I do this?

Your docker run command:

```
docker run -it --rm --name test --add-host api:192.168.43.8 -p 80:80 apachehttpd
```

**1st Thing:** The -`-add-host` flag add value to /etc/hosts in your container `/etc/hosts` so http://api will also response inside the container if ping inside that container.
This is how will ping response inside container
[image]

**2nd Thing:** Edit your host `etc/hosts` file and add

```
api 192.168.43.8 [your ip]
```

This is how you can see in Browser.
[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is `192.168.43.8` an arbitrary IP address or specific to the container?

Comment: No its your hosts IP. goto wifi information or run ifconfig or ipconfig you will get your ip

Comment: If any issue u can ask ;)

Comment: This worked, thanks. I looked at the `--add-host` argument in the docs but didn't realize this is what it did.